# How to emit only resolved value with Rxjs 5 mergeAll operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

How to emit only resolved promise with mergeAll operator.

```
var s1 = Rx.Observable.from([1,3,2])
var s2 = Rx.Observable.from([4,5,6])
var samplePromise = val => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{    
setTimeout(()=> {if(val==3) reject(new Error(val)); else resolve(val);},val*1000)});

var mergedSource= Rx.Observable.merge(s1,s2)
  .map(val => samplePromise(val))        
  .mergeAll()
  .catch(err=>console.log('err' , err)) 
var subscribeTwo = mergedSource.subscribe(val => console.log('Example:', val));
```

At this example ,  when val=3 throw error and doesnt emit others. 
How to skip rejected promises , I wanna emit only resolved promise value.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer without mergeAll operator. ﻿
    ﻿

```
var s1 = Rx.Observable.from([1,3,2])
var s2 = Rx.Observable.from([4,5,6])
var samplePromise = val => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
setTimeout(()=> {if(val!=3) resolve(val);  else reject('hata') },val*1000)
} );
var exampleTwo = Rx.Observable.merge(s1,s2)
  .flatMap(val => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(samplePromise(val)).catch(err=>Rx.Observable.empty()))


var subscribeTwo = exampleTwo.subscribe(val => console.log('Exampl:', val),err=>console.log("onError" ,err),()=>console.log('completed'));
```